# Unexpected token "else" while compiling ejs

Tags: conditional-statements, ejs

```
<% if (p.type === "boolean") { %>
    <label class="form-label"><%= p.name%></label>
    <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" name="<%= p.name%>[value]=" true " [(ngModel)]="model.<%=p .name%>">&nbsp;&nbsp;True
    <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" name="<%= p.name%>" [value]="false" [(ngModel)]="model.<%= p.name%>">&nbsp;&nbsp;False

<% } else if (p.type === "date"){ %>
    <label class="form-label"><%= p.name%></label>
    <input type="date" class="text-input" name="<%= p.name%>" [ngModel]="model.<%= p.name%> | date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh:ii'" (ngModelChange)="model.<%= p.name%> = $event">
<% } else { %>
    <label class="form-label"><%= p.name%></label>
    <input type="date" class="text-input" name="<%= p.name%>" [ngModel]="model.<%= p.name%> | date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh:ii'" (ngModelChange)="model.<%= p.name%> = $event">
<% } %>
```

Can anyone help me out here with this code here returning me an error

> Unexpected token `else` while compiling ejs

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour and you will understand [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail and error code... people are more willing to help you so we both can learn. Question moved to editing. Reviewing finished. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a typo in the question, but the attributes for the first input run together. The name attribute isn't closed before the value attribute.